# How to create a table in a newly created database in PostgreSQL?

Tags: node.js, postgresql

I want to create a database and a table in that database.

I create a new database and then a new table "users".
But the error "relation already exists" appears.
Yes, I already have a table "users", but it exists in another database.
But I want this table in the newly created database.

```
  import pkg from 'pg'; // node-postgres

  const { Client } = pkg;
  const client = new Client({
    host: ***,
    user: ***,
    password: ***,
  });

  await client.connect();

  await client.query(`
    CREATE DATABASE book_review_app;
  `);

  await client.query(`
    CREATE TABLE USERS (
      id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
      name character varying NOT NULL,
      email character varying NOT NULL UNIQUE,
      password varchar NOT NULL
    );
  `);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your client is still connected to the original `***` database, not to the newly created one. You'll need to open a new connection (create a new client) to `book_review_app`.